# How to insert xml process instruction upon upload on database

Tags: php, mysql, xml, xslt, domdocument

I found a code from one of the questions here on SO. I wonder where I will put this code on my upload function so it will insert this line:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="foreach_template.xsl"?>
```

before it would be uploaded on the database.

*note: I have this table on the database which has the following columns:

```
id - int(3)
title - varchar(50)
name - varchar(50)
type - varchar(25)
size - int(10)
content - mediumblob
```

*note: Also I have a folder where the xml files are uploaded

uploadprocess.php

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';

if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0)
{
$title = $_POST['title'];
$tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
//$fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

$xml = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['userfile']['name']));
$filename = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string(pathinfo($xml, PATHINFO_FILENAME)));
$ext = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string(".xml"));
$file = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($filename.$ext));
$full_local_path = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string('../xml/images/'.$filename.$ext));
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["userfile"]["name"]));
$loc = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string('xml/images/'));

if ($_FILES["userfile"]["type"] == "text/xml")
{

    $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    $content = addslashes($content);
    fclose($fp);

    $query = "INSERT INTO xmltable (title, name, size, type, content) ".
    "VALUES ('$title','$file', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$content')";
    mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], $full_local_path);

    echo "<script> alert ('upload successful'); location.href='upload.php';</script>";
}
else
{
    echo "<script> alert('Invalid File Type'); history.back(); </script>";
}
}
?>
```

upload.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>XML Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="font-family:verdana;padding:50px 10px 0px 0px;border:5px solid #4D4D4D;">
        <form action="uploadprocess.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <center>
            <p>
                TITLE OF THE ARTICLE &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="title" type="text" id="title" /><br /><br />
                <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">
                <input name="userfile" type="file" id="userfile" />
                <input name="upload" type="submit" class="box" id="upload" value=" Upload ">
            </p>
        </center>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
        <table border="1" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" width="100px">ID</td>
                <td align="center" width="100px">TITLE</td>
                <td align="center" width="100px">LINK</td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            include ('connection.php');

            $page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;

            $resultsPerPage = 5;
            $startResults = ($page - 1) * $resultsPerPage;

            $numberOfRows = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query('SELECT id FROM xmltable'));
            $totalPages = ceil($numberOfRows / $resultsPerPage);

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM xmltable LIMIT $startResults, $resultsPerPage");
            while ($output = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
            {
                echo "<tr><td>".$output['id']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$output['title']."</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                ?>
                <a class="del" href="/xml/images/<?php echo $output['name']; ?>" class="del">View Article</a>
                </td></tr>
                <?php
            }
                ?>
    </div>
        <div id="pagination">
            <div id="pagiCount">
                <center>
                    <?php

                    echo '<span id="prev"> <a href="?page=1">| First |</a></span>';

                    if ($page > 1)
                    {
                        echo '<span id="prev"> <a href="?page='.($page - 1).'">| Prev |';
                    }

                    for($i = 1; $i <= $totalPages; $i++)
                    {
                        if($i == $page)
                            echo '<strong>'.$i.'</strong>';
                        else
                            echo '<a href="?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
                    }

                    if ($page < $totalPages)
                        echo '<span id="next"> <a href="?page='.($page + 1).'">| Next |</a></span>';

                    echo '<a href="?page='.$totalPages.'">| Last |</a>';

                    ?>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

and view.php

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';

$name=$_GET['name'];

$sql="SELECT * FROM xmltable WHERE name = '$name'";
$rs=mysql_query($sql);
if (!$rs)
{
echo "failed to connect";
}
else
{
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    show_source("images/".$row['name']);
}
}
?>
```

Where can I put this code? And is it correct?

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><root/>');
$dom->insertBefore($dom->createProcessingInstruction('xml-stylesheet', 'type="text/xsl" href="foreach_template.xsl"'), $dom->documentElement);
echo $dom->saveXml();
```

Sorry if you find it long to read. Please help. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';

if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0)
{
    $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
    //$fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

    if ($_FILES['userfile']['type'] == 'text/xsl')
    {
        echo "<script> alert('Invalid File Type'); history.back(); </script>";
    }
    else if($_FILES['userfile']['type'] != 'text/xml')
    {
        echo "<script> alert('Invalid File Type'); history.back(); </script>";
    }
    else
    {
        $userfile = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['userfile']['name']));
        $filename = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string(pathinfo($userfile, PATHINFO_FILENAME)));
        $ext = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string(".xml"));
        $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["userfile"]["name"]));
        $loc = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string('xml/images/'));
        $xslt = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($filename.$ext));

        $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
        $xml->load($tmpName);

        $xml->insertBefore($xml->createProcessingInstruction('xml-stylesheet', 'type="text/xsl" href="xsl/foreach_template.xsl"'), $xml->documentElement);

        $xml->formatOutput = true;

        $xml->saveXml();
        $xml->save($tmpName);

        $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
        $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
        $content = addslashes($content);
        fclose($fp);

        print_r($tmpName);
        var_dump($tmpName);

        $full_local_path = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string('../xml/images/'.$filename.$ext));

        move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $full_local_path);

        $query = "INSERT INTO xmltable (name, size, type, content) "."VALUES ('$xslt', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$content')";
        mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');

        echo "<script> alert ('upload successful'); location.href='upload.php';</script>";
    }
}
?>
```